# What is the name for types of games like Phage Wars?

Tags: terminology

What's the generic name for strategy games where you have nodes that can be used to take over other neutral or enemy nodes, usually where each owned node generates power? Here's a few I've found by searching "games like [example]":

- Phage wars
- Solarmax
- Nano Wars
- Auralux
- dotHack
- Bubble Domination
- Galcon
- Eufloria
- Oil Rush

I find myself really drawn to these types of games, and never know what to call them.

Answer (score 2):

Typically this distinct game design element (played on a graph of nodes and edges) is referred to as a *node-based* game.

It's usually not seen as a distinct genre by itself, but tacked on as a qualifier to more distinctly describe a game.

For example, if your game is a *node-based RTS*, that means that the game takes place on a grid of nodes, can be controlled and evolves in real-time, and has some element of strategy such as unit types or economy.

Answer (score -3):

They are called "Turn Based Strategy" or simply "TBS" because you do exactly that, take each turn separately. This is opposed to "Real Time Strategy" or "RTS" where both you and your opponent move at the same time constantly.

Comment: Eufloria is very much real time and niet turn based.  Same for Galcon iirc.